# Проблема со сборкой libvpx

Tags: c++, mingw, libvpx

При сборке библиотеки libvpx с помощью MSYS (для MinGW) получил файл libvpx.a. При попытке скомпилировать [пример](http://www.webmproject.org/docs/webm-sdk/example_simple_decoder.html) получаю кучу undefined references:

```
g++ -m32 -static    -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/test1 build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o -L/D/Libraries/libvpx/ -lvpx
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:107: undefined reference to `die'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:109: undefined reference to `vpx_video_reader_open'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:111: undefined reference to `die'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:114: undefined reference to `die'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:116: undefined reference to `vpx_video_reader_get_info'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:118: undefined reference to `get_vpx_decoder_by_fourcc'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:120: undefined reference to `die'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:125: undefined reference to `die_codec'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:127: undefined reference to `vpx_video_reader_read_frame'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:132: undefined reference to `vpx_video_reader_get_frame'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:134: undefined reference to `die_codec'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:137: undefined reference to `vpx_img_write'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:144: undefined reference to `die_codec'
D:\Projects\CPP_test\Test1/main.cpp:149: undefined reference to `vpx_video_reader_close'
```

Что ему не хватает, почему не работает файл библиотеки? Неужели я должен собрав библиотеку, подтягивать отдельные .с файлы ,чтобы оно заработало?

Comment: Очевидно же, что линковщик не может найти библиотеку. Проверяйте наличие файла библиотеки в нужном месте и/или настройки сборки проекта.

Comment: Так если бы он её не нашёл, была бы ошибка в первой строке, где -lvpx

Comment: Потому что вы получили **статическую** библиотеку, а пытаетесь использовать **динамическую**! Естественно линковшик не находит её, что вам в первом комментарии и сказали.

Comment: Так как я её должен подключать? В параметрах линковщика пишу -lvpx, также как и с другими библиотеками - я так подключал и opencv, и libjpeg статические. Тут какой-то особый случай?

Comment: (Если хотите, чтобы видели ваши ответы на комментарии, пишите имя пользователя вначале.) Подключать так же, как и другие объектники, т.е. прямым использованием имени libvpx.a.

Comment: @0andriy, пробовал и подтягивать библиотеку через интерфейс IDE, и писать в строке сборщика -lvpx - безрезультатно. Мне просто кажется, что в данный файл libvpx.a не входит весь функционал SDK, так как например, демонстрационный код ресайза видео собирается, а код записи WebM файла нет из-за undefined reference-ов. Я не указывал никаких дополнительных флагов при `./confugure`, и в `./configure --help` не нашёл инструкций по подключению остального функционала библиотеки. А может такие инструкции всё-таки есть?